# Passing arguments to objects in C++ - Please explain the logic behind this?

Tags: c++

I started learning C++ and now I am lost, I don't see the logic in this. simply does not make sense to me **how it is possible that I can add arguments to an object** and then those arguments are used by the program. Sure I can memorize this feature, but can someone please explain the logic behind this? Everything else in C++ makes sense, I guess this probably does too, only I don't see it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class Person{
  private:
     string name;
     int age;

  public:
     Person(){
       name = "undefined";
       age = 0;
     };
     Person(string newname){
       name = newname;
       age = 0;
     };
     Person(string newname, int newage){
       name = newname;
       age = newage;
     };

     string toString(){
       stringstream ss;
       ss << "Name is: " << name << " Age is : " << age;
       return ss.str();
    };

 };


int main()
{
  Person person1;
  Person person2("David");  // I don't get this ???
  Person person3("Mia", 35); // // I don't get this ???

  cout << person1.toString() << endl;
  cout << person2.toString() << endl;
  cout << person3.toString() << endl;

  return 0;
};
```

Comment: See Constructors in C++ https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm

Comment: You really should be using a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn C++ from.  It will explain things like this.

Comment: Put breakpoints on the three constructors and run it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site that teaches programming.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is how these values ("Mia", 35) are passed from object to a constructor, I don't see the logic behind it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement: `Person person1;` is calling this constructor:

```
Person();
```

This `Person person2("David");` is calling this constructor:

```
Person(string newname);
```

And this `Person person3("Mia", 35);`  is calling this constructor:

```
Person(string newname, int newage);
```

Since constructors are **functions** that initialize the object of class Person, they can receive arguments, like any function.

Answer (score 3):

You are actually calling the **constructors** when you say you're passing arguments to objects. **Constructors** with matching signatures are called.

When you write `Person person1;`, default constructor which is

```
Person(){
    name = "undefined";
    age = 0;
};
```

is called.
When you write `Person person2("David");`,

```
Person(string newname){
    name = newname;
    age = 0;
};
```

is called. 
And finally, when you do `Person person3("Mia", 35);`,

```
Person(string newname, int newage){
    name = newname;
    age = newage;
};
```

is called.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a new C++ class, with its members as your choice, each one of these functions as a regular variable (or pointers, or instances of other classes, etc.) which is a concept you are already familiar with.

So when you instantiate a new instance of the class, the compiler knows exactly how much memory it should allocate, and what is the inner structure of it - how to divide that memory into smaller pieces corresponding to the class members.
And that is how, when you call a constructor, it knows how to "add the arguments" to your instance.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but could you at least try to write decent correct english please.

Comment: This is my best english, if you have any constructive comments I would like to hear.

Comment: choice, them -> these, instance, class, pieces

Comment: You are still missing one :)